# What is the usefulness of CHECK, UNITCHECK and INIT blocks in Perl?

Tags: perl, compilation

I know what they all do, but have never found myself in a situation where I've needed any of them. I've used `BEGIN` blocks on many occasions and `END`s once in a while. `BEGIN` is especially useful when you need to tweak the environment before code gets run, and I've used `END` in certain debugging situations to trap important state information for hard-to-track-down fatal errors.

Have you ever used `CHECK`, `UNITCHECK` or `INIT`? If so, what for? And would a `BEGIN` block  not have sufficed for some reason?

The documentation for the blocks is on [PerlDoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a package `import` function which would do some heavy duty processing and then make an `eval` call. How do you debug something like that? The import function gets run when you `use` the module, which takes place at compile time (like it was inside a BEGIN block). For some reason (I think it was because I needed to pass parameters to `import` with heredoc notation, but it could have been something else), it wasn't good enough to say `require Module; Module->import(@args)`.

So my workaround was to build the string for `eval` in `import`, and save it another variable.
Then I ran the `eval` in an `INIT` block. When you ran the debugger, the very first execution point was at the start of the `INIT` block and I could use the debugger to step through the `eval` statement.

Comment: Now I remember why I didn't want to do `require Module;Module->import(@stuff)`. It was because I already had a suite of test scripts I wanted to be able to debug, and I didn't want to edit the `use Module` statement in every file.

Comment: You don't need to go through those contortions to debug compile-time code.  Just place $DB::single=1 anywhere in your source and the debugger will stop at that point, no matter which phase of processing the program is in. (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#Debugging-compile-time-statements)

Answer (score 8):

An interesting use of CHECK blocks is in "Advanced Perl programming" by Simon Cozens (O'Reilly) in Chapter 1, in "Doing things later with CHECK" section. He shows how to implement "final" java-like attribute

Also, Devel::Sub::Trace uses INIT blocks to incert traces (this info is from POD for Devel::Hook which is a module used for working with those named blocks)

Comment: Also, I never tried it but these *might* be plausibly leveraged for some interesting mocking approaches - if someone has an idea, feel free to expand on this possibility as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Well `BEGIN` blocks are run at compile time, as you know. So I keep it to code that needs to be run in order for my module to be imported.

I wrote a script wrapper, to do everything that was being done in boilerplate code that occurred in a couple hundred scripts.

- There were things I had to do to get the module reading to be `use`-d. That I ran in `BEGIN` blocks and `import` sub.
- But there was also all that boilerplate that *initialized* the services the script would use. Therefore, I ran these actions in the `INIT` blocks.
- And ran necessary cleanup and exit code in the `END` blocks.

I think CHECK makes sense if you write modules with XS engines, but I have only used it a handful of times. One time I think it was to check out the suggestions in *Intermediate Perl*. And I can't offhand remember the other reasons.

But I use `INIT` blocks when I feel that code is more part of the script, than setting up the module. In essence, I only do what is necessary during compile time.

Comment: Axeman - for the initialization, could you please clarify what were your usages where INIT block was providing something special not achievable by simply placing init code at the start of the regular program? Is it just for visualization/ease of maintenance?

Comment: @DVK: I've used INIT blocks in modules to perform class initialization; the user shouldn't have to know about that sort of thing. Unfortunately, PAR::Packer has problems with scheduled blocks (INIT and CHECK in particular) so this doesn't work for modules that might be distributed that way. I usually end up ripping out the INIT block in favor of an `initialize()` sub that gets called the first time the constructor is invoked.

Comment: CHECK blocks have nothing to do with XS modules.

Comment: @rurban,  You're quibbling about a case that *Programming Perl* says "you'll rarely write a CHECK block yourself, unless you're writing such a module [backend or code generator]." If XS is not your speed, then generating op codes is *definitely* not your speed. And the reason that the OP has never needed to use a CHECK block is that he has not been writing Perl that needed it.

Answer (score 2):

**perlmod** explains those special blocks but indeed only `BEGIN` and `END` are commonly used.
They are just arrays of CVs, LIFO or FIFO.
Those blocks allow seperate timings when code is run, independent on the location in the source file. So you can keep code sections together, but they are executed at different times (`PHASES`).

**CHECK** was added initially to run the compiler suite **O** (`-MO=C...`) in a fixed order after module initialization (use package), and before the main program, to be able store the execution context there. This seperates compile-time (before) from run-time (after).
`perl -c` stops after CHECK.

As I am the maintainer of the compilers, I use CHECK and -MO= extensively. My modules `compile()` methods are called by **O** within a CHECK block. With **Od** (*debugging O*) I call the `compile` method not in CHECK, but later in INIT, so the debugger steps into it. The debugger does not step into CHECK blocks per default, you have to force it with `$DB::single=1` or use **Od**.

**UNITCHECK** was added later to fine-grain module compilation and loading, esp. `.pmc` files.

I've never used that so far. It can also happen at run-time, so I might use it for type checks of run-time loaded modules.

**INIT** was then added to allow seperate class initialization.

I rarely use that, but it is handy.

Comment: Apparently, you missed: "Have you ever used CHECK, UNITCHECK or INIT? If so, what for? And would a BEGIN block not have sufficed for some reason?" That kind of thin explanation, the OP can get anywhere.